# What does «spec-speak» mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

There is a sentence in this [article](http://www.maximumpc.com/computer-hardware-guide-2013/#page-1):

> Continue reading to begin your crash course in PC spec-speak.

Googling gave some links to MaximumPC and another [article](http://reslife.net/architectural-spec-speak-sixteen-ways-to-understand-your-architect-part-1/) with the title «Architectual spec-speak».

I'd like to know what does this word exactly mean? Does the meaning depend on context? And the hyphen, is it optional?

Comment: It means the same thing as "techno-babble".  (Basically, it just means the technical jargon related to the sort of technology being considered.  Not a specific language, and may be very vaguely interpreted to mean anything from highly technical stuff to text that's merely filled with silly acronyms.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"spec" is short for "specification". You're about to hit a section specifically devoted to discussion of PC Specifications - spec-speak.